Write a temporary one-liner to the bottom line after opening a file?
When opening a file whose filetype extension is governed by ftdetect, i wish to write a single-line to the vim status bar (bottom line) that says something like:
To enable syntax highlighting for this widget, enter in ":syntax on".

The above message need not be permanent or can be even timed out, but it should not interfere with normal set statusline= operation.
This way, the plugin developer can inform the vim user that its syntax is available and this particular filetype (as determined by ftdetect) can leave the massive syntax file disabled unless the vim-user needs such syntax highlighting
I'd rather take a 20-odd-line vimscript snippet than having yet another plugin dependency.
Is this doable, or practical?

Why not let the user choose once and for all filetypes by writing syntax on in their vimrc or not?

I think it is because syntax on|off is a binary and not tri-state (third one being, it depends on what that specific plugin prefers. I would imagine such an end-user would like to have syntax on for most file(type)s (but not the configuration-oriented file being handled by large heavy-CPU, strict-validation, syntax vimscript.)  Of course, I am assuming that syntax on means applied toward ALL windows, or something. If so, a plugin should be able to turn it off and only toward its own window, right?

Alternatives: echomsg, use a popup… but I would find those annoying if coming from a plugin unnecessarily

Even if it is a one-shot reminder and goes away afterward?  Hence, statusline (from what I am reading)?  Rather not use popup

I just tried echomsg, a non-starter approach from a practical user interface experience POV.  Is it possible to write something to a random location on a screen and it is gone before the next ordinary keystroke (not just ENTER)?

What about adding support for a yet another user-definable variable such as nftablesyntax=on. That seems to be the prevaling winds around vim community. However, it is nice to remind the vim user of their options.

No, it is not. It is true annoyance. What about adding a variable Variables may be used only to tune code a bit: relaxed error checking, some non-standard language extensions, etc.

There are things I don't understand. syntax on/off is global and applies to absolutely everything. We can't have it turned on in a window and off in another. At best, we can disable the execution of a syntax file for a given buffer, on the condition the buffer and the syntax file target the same filetype. We can even image ways to activate/deactivate the highlighting in a buffer. But this can't be done with :syntax which is a global choice that affects everything.

Otherwise for the case I need to notify end-user about things, I have a few different ways to do it in my library plugin: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md#warnings -> lh#common#warning_msg() (root function:  kind of colored version of echom), lh#notify#once() (wrapper that does it once), lh#warning#emit() (another wrapper that records warnings and their callstack in order to display them in the quickfix window later). The code..

You're overthinking it, if a user installs your plugin for syntax for nftables, that means they intend to have syntax for nftables. If the performance of the "massive" syntax file is a problem for them, they're likely to find a way around that.
